# converting from rpy to rpy2 Error 2 system can not find the file specified

Tags: python, r

I had rpy on windows server 2008 set up. It did a simple

```
from rpy import *
```

and

```
r.assign(blah blah)
```

and all was well.
but then we moved to windows server 2016
and installed rpy2
and realized I needed to changed to

```
import rpy2.robjects as r
```

but now doing the import above gives me a long error ending in

```
c:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\subprocess.py line 641 in _execute_child_ startupinfo
WindowsError [Error 2] The System can not find the file specified
```

setting a global var R_Home doesn't seem to affect this error as I can delete it and th code still throws the error.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the latest R install 
Then make sure you add to your environment PATH the R bin directory
and then set R_HOME to r-3.4.4 dir and R_USER to c:\users[yourusername]

I was working in a virtual environment through rdp and these changes above were not registering until and I had logged out and then logged back in. That was the main issue.